# Run full EF query on SQL server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I want to return via my API the last result for each 'device'. The devices regularly communicate with the API, there is a record of each communication. I want to pull the record of the last communication for each device.

Given the number of records which could be in the table, I want to ensure that I'm processing the query in SQL rather than pulling all the records and processing the remainder of the query in memory.

Using LINQ such as

```
            var r = _context.HeartBeat.GroupBy(x => x.SourceDeviceIdent)
            .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(c => c.HeartBeatDateTimeReceived).First())
            .ToList();
```

I'm hitting error

```
.OrderByDescending(c => c.HeartBeatDateTimeReceived)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

The following gives the required output:

```
var result = _context.HeartBeat.ToList()
            .GroupBy(g => g.SourceDeviceIdent)
            .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(o => o.HeartBeatDateTimeReceived).First()).ToList();
```

However I'm assuming this is processing in memory rather than at the SQL server.

How do I convert my query into a query which is processed entirely in the database?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for this in LINQ is a bit simpler than what you tried:

```
var q = from d in db.Devices
        select d.HeartBeats.OrderByDescending(h => h.HeartBeatDateTimeReceived).First();

var r = q.ToList();
```

Which translates to:

```
  SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[DeviceId], [t0].[HeartBeatDateTimeReceived]
  FROM [Devices] AS [d]
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[DeviceId], [t].[HeartBeatDateTimeReceived]
      FROM (
          SELECT [h].[Id], [h].[DeviceId], [h].[HeartBeatDateTimeReceived], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [h].[DeviceId] ORDER BY [h].[HeartBeatDateTimeReceived] DESC) AS [row]
          FROM [HeartBeat] AS [h]
      ) AS [t]
      WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
  ) AS [t0] ON [d].[Id] = [t0].[DeviceId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedure, take a look in this link [EF Stored Procedure](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)